# What does the instruction _exit(1) do?

Tags: unix

I am trying to learn to code in UNIX and despite this question being all around I cannot seem to find any answer to what this instruction does. All of the answers I get either refer to the instruction `exit()` or `_exit(0)` and `_exit(2)`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The values are the so-called exit-values of your application. Generally, when a program has zero as an exit-value, this means that everything was good, while other numbers generally indicate some kind of error value.